# Flink Elasticsearch sink success handler

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-batch

I use Flink Elasticsearch sink to bulk insert the records to ES.

I want to do an operation after the record is successfully synced to Elasticsearch. There is a failureHandler by which we can retry failures. Is there a successHandler in flink elasticsearch sink?

**Note**: I couldn't do the operation before adding the record to the bulk-processor because there is no guarantee that the record is synced with ES?  I want to do the operation only after the record is synced to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the Elasticsearch sink offers this feature. I think you will have to extend the sink to add this functionality.

Comment: what do you mean by `extend the sink`?

Comment: I mean implement a new sink by extending (in the java sense) or subclassing the relevant classes from the existing sink to add this functionality.